# Unsupported operand type for +=; 'int' and 'list' in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

new to Python and recently I have been trying out recursion. The following is my code:

```
def recursive_sum(n_n_l):
    total = 0
    for element in n_n_l:
        if type(element) == list:
            total += recursive_sum(element)
        else:
            total += element
    return total


nnl = [11, [12, 13], 14]
print(recursive_sum(nnl))
```

All goes well when I use online IDEs and I get the expected result of 50, but when running it on my computer terminal I receive this message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'.
```

Is there something that requires updating? Currently running on python 3.7.5 and using Atom text editor vers. 1.37.0 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am using pycharm and it perfectly works, it gives 50 as output

Comment: Your code executes fine

Comment: when you say, computer terminal, do you save it as a .py file and execute the py file ?

Comment: Your code works as typed. Please include the full error message.

Comment: @venkatakrishnan, yes I save it as a .py file and execute as a .py file.

Comment: @DYZ, full error message is as such:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File, line 47, in <module>
    print(recursive_sum(nnl))
File, line 42, in recursive_sum
    total += element
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: I do not see an immediate cure to the problem, but try replacing `type(element) == list` with `isinstance(element, list)`.